# Handle keydown events in AngularDart component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an AngularDart component that I would like to receive global keydown events. I tried this:

```dart
  Stream<KeyEvent> _keyStream;
  StreamSubscription<KeyEvent> _keyStreamSubscription;

  @override
  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
    _keyStream = KeyEvent.keyPressEvent.forTarget(document.body);
    _keyStreamSubscription = _keyStream.listen((keyEvent) =>
      window.console.log('KeyPress event detected ${keyEvent.charCode}'));
  }

  @override
  void ngOnDestroy() {
    _keyStreamSubscription.cancel();
  }
```

However when I press a key I get this error in the devtools console

```
EXCEPTION: InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.
STACKTRACE: 
package:stack_trace                                <fn>
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 144:18  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                  runUnary
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 141:18  [_runUnary]

dart:sdk_internal                                           forTarget
package:human_sota/src/mnist_component.dart 34:41           ngOnInit
dart:sdk_internal                                           _async
package:human_sota/src/mnist_component.dart 33:24           ngOnInit
package:human_sota/app_component.template.dart 152:27       detectChangesInternal
package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 384:7         detectChanges
package:angular/src/core/linker/view_container.dart 67:15   detectChangesInNestedViews
package:human_sota/app_component.template.dart 69:14        detectChangesInternal
package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 384:7         detectChanges
package:human_sota/app_component.template.dart 186:17       detectChangesInternal
package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 384:7         detectChanges
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 164:18  [_runTick]
package:angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 140:7   tick
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 132:18           <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                           run
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 129:18           [_run]
dart:sdk_internal                                           runGuarded
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 300:23           runGuarded
package:angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 53:15         <fn>
package:stack_trace                                         <fn>
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 144:18           <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                           runUnary
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 141:18           [_runUnary]
dart:sdk_internal                                           add
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 243:54           [_checkStable]
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 176:5            [_onLeave]
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 134:9            <fn>
dart:sdk_internal                                           run
package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 129:18           [_run]
```

Why?

Comment: I don't know about that `forTarget` method, but did you try to simply use `document.body.onKeyPress.listen` ?

Comment: This usually happens when the stream is being subscribed twice. Can you check if that is happening anywhere in your code.